# Run Mysql query with different data format DD-MMM-YY

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

1 . Below query works fine

```
select * 
  from order_details 
 where date between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-27';
```

2 . In order to support below API request

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/BotMetrics/get/?fromdate=03-MAR-21&todate=16-MAR-21`

**Note :** here the date value will be coming externally as DD-MMM-YY

I want to run below query but don't get back any results

```
select * 
  from order_details 
 where date between '03-MAR-21' and '16-MAR-21';
```

API code

```
@app.route('/BotMetrics/get/' ,methods=['get'])
def user():
    fromdate = request.args.get('fromdate',None)
    todate = request.args.get('todate',None)
    # environment =  request.args.get('environment',None)
    con = Get_hdb()
    cursor1 = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print(fromdate)
    print(todate)
    cursor1.execute("select * from order_details where date between %s and %s",(fromdate,todate))
    row = cursor1.fetchall()
    length = len(row)
    print(length)
    resp = jsonify({'"BOT-OC"':length})
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp
```

date fields are stored in below format currently

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your image does not show the format you are using. Try `describe order_details;` and update your post with the details.

Comment: @symcbean thanks for responding , I have updated the details please check and let me know

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. For database tables, include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @tadman will that help api to consume DD-MMM-YYY format? if yes can you let me what changes i need to make to my execute query?

Comment: I mean you can use Python to switch between the date formats. Convert from database to API version to make queries, and vice-versa if necessary. Things like [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) are invaluable here as you can customize the format for parsing.

Comment: Are you implementing this API and trying to support alternate date formats? Is that a hard requirement or some wishful thinking? Forcing [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is safer than trying to handle all kinds of other forms, many of which are impossible to differentiate reliably, like `MM-DD-YY` and `DD-MM-YY`.

Answer (score 0):

Made the following code changes to resolve the issue

```
 fromdate = request.args.get('fromdate',None)
 todate = request.args.get('todate',None)
 fromdate_new =  datetime.strptime(fromdate, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 todate_new =   datetime.strptime(todate, '%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Next time use a date/datetime data type for your database attribute.